# How to load data from MySql database into list(Console-Based app)?

Tags: c#, mysql, console-application

I have created a database with 1 table "emp" and have some data in it. Now every time i start the app, i  want a list to fetch the data from db and save it in list because i want to perform some calculations like tax and Gross-Salary on data at runtime for display only(don't want to save it in db ). I have tried many times but i am unable to understand how this can be done. This is my code:

Main Class:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        empDB empDB1 = new empDB();
        List<emplyee> empLST1 = new List<emplyee>();

        if (empLST1 == null)
        {
            empDB1.loadLST(out empLST1);
        }
    }
```

empDB Class:

```
class empDB
{
    private string ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;DATABASE=hris;uid=root;Password=123456;";

    internal void loadLST(out List<emplyee> loadedLST)
    {
        string query = "select name, grade from emp";
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                List<employee> returnedLst = new List<employee>();
                returnedLst.Add(rdr["name"].ToString(), rdr["grade"].ToString());
            }
            loadedLst = returnedLst;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea even if my approach is right or not. I have googled it a few times but i just started working in .net a few days ago so i don't understand how to do it.

*Okay i tried **this** and it also **dosn't** work:*

```
internal void GetDatabaseList()
{
    List<employee> databases = new List<employee>();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable tbl = con.GetSchema("Databases");
        con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            databases.Add(row["hris"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use Entity Framework? Is "raw" ADO .NET is a requirement?

Comment: @Dennis Yes it is required, as i haven't learned Entity Framework, so i am not allowed to use it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    empDB empDB1 = new empDB();
    List<emplyee> empLST1 = new List<emplyee>();

    **if (empLST1 == null)
    {
        empDB1.loadLST(out empLST1);
    }**
}
```

this will always be false because you defined empLST1 as a new List, meaning its not null

try this

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    empDB empDB1 = new empDB();
    List<Employee> empLST1 = new List<Employee>();

    empDB1.loadLST(ref empLST1);
}

public class empDB
{
    public void loadLst(ref List<Employee> loadedLST)
    {
        string query = "select name, grade from emp";
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                emp.Grade = rdr["grade"].ToString();

                loadedLST.Add(emp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay got it, do you have any solution for loadLST method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that that `employee` class looks like this:

```
class employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

I'd rewrite `loadLST` like this:

```
internal List<employee> loadLST()
{
    string query = "select name, grade from emp";

    // we should dispose IDisposable implementations:
    // connection, command and data reader
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // it is hard to maintain manual mapping
            // between query results and objects;
            // let's use helper like Automapper to make this easier
            Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, employee>();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return Mapper.Map<List<employee>>(rdr);
        }
    }
}
```

Improvements:

- `IDisposable` implementations must be disposed explicitly (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
- to avoid manual mapping code, which maps the result from data reader and object (`employee` instance in your case), the code uses [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) package
- exception handling and `out` parameter are thrown away. There's no need for exception handling and `out` parameter here, unless you're writing method like `TryToDoSomething` (and even in that case your method must return `bool` to indicate the state of operation, and catch only specific exceptions instead of `Exception`).

Also note, that your code doesn't match [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (e.g., `employee` should be `Employee`).

Comment: @MansoorAkram: of course you have to install NuGet package (see description at automapper.org).